# Monitoring hanging processes

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, monit, daemontools

I need to monitor hanging processes on the output of `ps -ef | grem GMC`...

What's the best way to do this without running this command manually and being stuck in front of a command line all day?  I'd like to our dev team to get an email whenever one of these processes hangs so we can investigate, or better yet, auto-killing dying processes.

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 (x86_64)
VERSION = 10
PATCHLEVEL = 1
LSB_VERSION="core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.0-x86_64"
Novell Open Enterprise Server 2 (x86_64)
VERSION = 2
BUILD = FCS
```

Comment: if you know what output you're looking for from the ps command, it should be as simple as writing a script and putting it in a cron

Comment: What happens when the process hangs ?

Answer (score 2):

A simple script like the one following does the magic:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESS=`ps auxw | grep GMC | grep -v grep`

if [ -z $PROCESS ]; then
  echo "Process GMC not running" | mail -s "Alert" yourmail@address.com
fi
```

Then run this every 5 minutes from your `crontab`.

You might also want to check tools like [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). Both these tools are open source utilities that check processes and restart them if they're not running.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will this tell me when it's stalled?

Comment: you can tune the script to do that as well.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Does the process write some kind of output/log?

Comment: What happens the the process hangs?